# Best way to write contributions header in php and all available tags like @author

Tags: php, phpdoc

[image]

I am working on a GitHub project https://github.com/qzoke/isbn-converter
I want to create a nice contribution header. So here are my questions :

1. All the variables or whatever like @author available.

few that i know are:

```
@author
@license
@version
@package
@subpackage
```

2. Best way to showcase values like

few use

```
@author www.website.com
```

few use

```
@author name<email>
```

and some just

```
@author name.
```

3. How and what should be name for package and sub package. subpackage is confusing , no idea if i should use file name in subpackage or same package name.
4. Is it ok to write description, keyword, contribution by in there.
5. What's the best way to reference license, just name (like GNU GPL v3.0) or name+weblink or link to local copy or copy of whole license text.
6. And which files should have such a header , just index.php , or header.php or every other.
7. And what to include in html commenting , if any.

Comment: How did this get -5 score in 3 minutes? It's not *that* terrible of a question...

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Appears to be a whole set of questions, none of which have any any indication that the asker has tried to make any progress.

Comment: Yeah but -5? How does that even happen

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen not -5 thats 6 downvote and a upvote.

Comment: @Richard , thnx for suggestion , edited

Comment: This question was originally tagged as php (a programming language) but is definitely not a programming question. The correct tags need to be used in order to get the right feedback,

Comment: @apokryfos , you can add tag u edited for me in answer because phpdoc is the answer i was searching for. i dont knew that it's called  phpdoc , so i was unable to find answer. I just searched for phpdoc and i can see whole lot of info more than i need. thnx apokryfos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the https://phpdoc.org/ documentation there is a number of tags recognised by the phpDocumentor listed at https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html.

Example source https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/author.html

> `Syntax: @author [name] [<email address>]`
>
> The @author tag can be used to indicate who has created Structural Elements or has made significant modifications to them. This tag MAY also contain an e-mail address. If an e-mail address is provided it MUST follow the author’s name and be contained in chevrons, or angle brackets, and MUST adhere to the syntax defined in section 3.4.1 of RFC5322.

All your points can be answered using the documentation of PHPDoc.

Few more PHPDoc Tags are :

```
@abstract
@access
@author
@copyright
@deprecated
@deprec
@example
@exception
@global
@ignore
@internal
@license
@link
@name
@magic
@package
@param
@return
@see
@since
@static
@staticvar
@subpackage
@throws
@todo
@var
@version
```

You can find more in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc